# Angular JS ng-repeat filter only items with a property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json file with keys like

```
[
 {
  "message": "Verify envelopes are properly loaded.",
  "hasFigure": false,
  "figureX": 0,
  "figureY": 0
 },
{
  "message": "Verify the paddle is in the down position.",
  "hasFigure": true,
  "figureX": 185,
  "figureY": 50
}
]
```

I need to put this into an ng-repeat but only show the items where `hasFigure` is `true`

I know it's a filter, but can't seem to get the syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `ng-show` / `ng-hide`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="item.hasFigure"></div>
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I could've sworn that one time I did it with a filter.

Comment: Problem here is that elements are created with hasFigure = false are placed in the DOM anyway and hidded. I think is a bit better to use ng-if instead of ng-show

Answer (score 3):

Your filter syntax would be

> For safer side use strict checking by adding `: true` at the end of
>   filter

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {'hasFigure': true}: true"></div>
```

Comment: @Steve does it helped you..As you were looking for filter I think?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="stuff in stuffs | filter: { hasFigure: true }">
```